# Sending outlook email with attachment c sharp

Tags: c#, outlook

I can't get the email to show up with attachment.  every thing else works except the attachment.  I have tried every thing I can possibly think of and coded it every way I can find online. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
public void createEmail(){
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application mailApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    MailItem mailItem = mailApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailItem.Subject = "Subject";
    mailItem.To = "Anyone@gmail.com";
    mailItem.Display(true);
    mailItem.Attachments.Add("C:\\File.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an attachment before calling the `Display` method:

```
public void createEmail()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application mailApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    MailItem mailItem = mailApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailItem.Subject = "Subject";
    mailItem.To = "Anyone@gmail.com";
    mailItem.Attachments.Add("C:\\File.txt");
    mailItem.Display(true);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i knew it had to be something stupid.